# How can I know about the type of the airplane before booking

Tags: air-travel, airlines, aircraft

How can I know the type of an airplane before reservation? I want to know if it is Boeing or Airbus and the model if it's possible. Can I use websites such as SkyScanner for this purpose?

Comment: Related: [How to find and compare flights carried out by a specific type of plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46093/how-to-find-and-compare-flights-carried-out-by-a-specific-type-of-plane/99175#99175)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can absolutely find out this information before booking, though it is subject to change.  [Kayak](http://kayak.com) definitely provides this functionality when opening the details of a given flight.  See the image I've included below.

[image]

In addition, most airline sites also provide this information.  However as far as I can tell, [SkyScanner](http://www.skyscanner.com) does **not** provide this information - or at least not where it's easily findable.  I've attached the corresponding SkyScanner information for the same flight, noting that there's no plane information provided.

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me how much it is probable an airplane change for a flight?
I am kind of afraid of flight, so I won't take any airplane.

Comment: It's very very unlikely.  The airlines really don't like doing it because of the hassle involved as they would need to rearrange many different plans.  It generally only happens if they find an issue in their pre-flight checklist and the plane changes to whatever's available and suitable for that airline at that airport.

Comment: @yashar If you are afraid of flying, depending on from where to where you are going, you might want to consider alternatives.  Your trip might take days or even a week rather than hours/half a day, but it could be a very interesting experience.  [Seat61](http://www.seat61.com/) has a lot of information.  However, the best rational reasons to choose other alternatives do not lie in safety, but in many other factors.

Comment: @yashar I do realize it's not your question but differences in safety (to the extent that those differences matter at all) will depend just as much on training, maintenance, etc. than on the specific aircraft type. Furthermore, for a specific route, you will mostly have the same type of plane no matter the airline (e.g. large wide-body jets on long-haul routes, etc.) and I don't think you can generally assume one of the big plane makers to be safer than the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter your flight number/information and see your plane from the booking panel, SeatGuru, FlightAware, and many more sources.