# List of flight routes where Air India flies the Boeing 747-400 and/or Boeing 787-800

Tags: air-travel, routes, aircraft, flight-search-engines, air-india

I am looking for routes where the Air India flies the 787 and 747 since i heard they are being used for domestic routes, i would like to try my luck.
I know a few for each, Frankfurt/London gets the 787, Dubai/Jeddah get the 747.
I read 
[How to find and compare flights carried out by a specific type of plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46093/how-to-find-and-compare-flights-carried-out-by-a-specific-type-of-plane).

I would like to know all flights from Mumbai that use B787 and B747 (Even A380).

Sadly, AI has lost one 747 in the [Arabian Sea New Years' Eve crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_India_Flight_855).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a complete timetable of all Air India flights at http://www.airindia.in/time-table.htm, and it has an option to filter by aircraft type (try `B787` or `B747`).

Google also turns up a PDF timetable with the same data at http://www.airindia.in/Images/pdf/TimeTable.pdf.

From Mumbai, it shows one 747 flight, nonstop to Hyderabad and continuing to Jeddah; and 787 flights nonstop to Delhi, London and Singapore, with continuing service to various other places.

Air India doesn't operate any A380 aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Boeing 787 & 747 are long-haul aircrafts, it is mainly used for international trips, esp. with high passenger numbers for profitability.

Always Boeing 787 routes:

1. The London to Delhi route flown as AI162 & AI116
2. The London to Mumbai route flown as AI130
3. The Mumbai to London route flown as AI131
4. The Frankfurt to Delhi route flown as  AI120
5. The Delhi to Frankfurt route flown as AI121
6. The Rome to Delhi route flown as AI122
7. The Delhi to Rome route flown as AI123
8. The Milan to Delhi route flown as AI138
9. The Delhi to Milan route flown as AI137
10. The Paris to Delhi route flown as AI142
11. The Delhi to Paris route flown as AI143
12. The Delhi to Vienna route flown as AI153
13. The Vienna to Delhi route flown as AI154
14. The Delhi to Moscow route flown as AI155
15. The Moscow to Delhi route flown as AI156
16. The Ahmedabad to London route flown as AI171 & AI175
17. The London to Ahmedabad route flown as AI172 & AI176

Occasionally, the 747 & 787 are used to fly these domestic flights:

1. [AI665](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC665/history/20170131/0230Z/VIDP/VABB) New Delhi - Mumbai, 787
2. [AI888](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC888/history/20170520/1330Z/VABB/VIDP) Mumbai - New Delhi, 787
3. [AI805](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC805/history/20170521/1430Z/VIDP/VABB) New Delhi - Mumbai, 747
4. [AI806](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC806/history/20170224/0230Z/VABB/VIDP) Mumbai - New Delhi, 747

source: https://www.quora.com/Does-Air-India-still-operates-its-fleet-of-Boeing-747-Aircrafts-If-yes-on-which-routes

Update: Air India has 4 Boeing 747 aircrafts listed at https://www.planespotters.net/production-list/search?fleet=Air-India&manufacturer=Boeing&type=747&fleetStatus=current,

tracking them, i got route information of each aircraft

1. https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/vt-evb
2. https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/vt-esp

Revealing flights along Mumbai-Hyderabad-Jeddah-Cochin-Jeddah-Hyderabad-Mumbai

Update: Adding a screenshot from air india website (http://www.airindia.in/time-table.htm).

[image]