# How many airline routes in the US still fly turboprops?

Tags: air-travel, airlines

I know that Horizon airlines, owned by Alaska still does but nowadays it’s difficult to find out the routes that still use Turboprops. And I heard these are being phased out quickly.

Comment: If they're being phased out, that's news to me. Turboprops are still an economically favorable choice for many regional routes, say, transporting 40-70 people at a time on distances less than 1000 miles. They're still being built as new -- for example ATR 42/72 or Dash 8.

Comment: Quite the contrary.  Most airlines are phasing out small regional jets (e.g. Canadair CRJ-100 and -200 planes) and replacing them with turboprops (e.g. Bombardier Dash 8-Q400s).  These turboprops are larger (70-80-seat) and more comfortable than the old, small turboprops.

Comment: Of possible interest: *[How to find and compare flights carried out by a specific type of plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46093)*

Comment: This is better off asked on https://aviation.stackexchange.com   Lots of commercial pilots hang out there

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1814/which-engine-is-more-efficient-between-turboprop-vs-jet

Comment: Thanks for referring me to aviation.stack-exchange.com and the other links.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: a lot, but dropping fast.

Working in the aviation industry I have access to some fun tools so I thought I'd look this up for you. Today (29 November 2017) there are 2,174 scheduled turboprop flights in the US.

Many of these (874) are in Alaska, but some other notable routes, in addition to the Horizon routes you mentioned, are run by Silver Airways, who fly Saab turboprops all over Florida and the Bahamas. American Airlines still has some old turboprops flying out of CLT and PHL, though those will be retired very soon (these are flown by regional airlines, not AA itself). United still has some regional flying on turboprops out of IAD as well.

Some other smaller turboprop operators with fairly large operations include Cape Air, Great Lakes Aviation, and Southern Airways Express.

Comment: What US operators are flying larger, newer turboprops like the Dash 8-Q400?

Comment: Near as I can tell it's just Horizon, though several airlines in Canada are flying them. American and United have the older models and most of the other turboprops are either Twin Otters or of the single engine variety.

Comment: WestJet and Air Canada are both flying them.  WestJet adopted them for its regional airline (it's the only plane that regional airline uses), and Air Canada is having its regional partners replace their CRJs with Q400s.