# Which Horizon airlines (Alaska airlines) routes still uses turboprop planes?

Tags: airlines, nostalgia, alaska-airlines

A few years ago, it used to be easier to find this answer. But nowadays it’s increasingly harder. I know that they used to do SJC to Burbank or LAX in turboprop, as well as between Spokane and Seattle or Boise to Seattle or somewhere in California or Portland.

Is the new Alaska airlines route between LAX and Mammoth lakes done in turboprop?

Comment: Related interest: *[How to find and compare flights carried out by a specific type of plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46093)*

Answer (score 2):

Alaska Airlines posts their [complete timetable](https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/timetables) in PDF format.  You can also see [specific routes](https://www.alaskaair.com/schedule).  Both include aircraft type.

The PDF timetable uses IATA aircraft codes, of which a table can be found [here](http://www.airlinecodes.co.uk/arctypes.asp) among other places.

Flights between LAX and MMH are shown with code DH8, which refers to the [De Havilland Canada DHC-8 Dash 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_Dash_8) series of turboprops.  In the specific route schedule this is shown as Q-400, referring to the model within this series which Horizon operates.  So the answer to your specific question is **yes**, flights on this route are operated with turboprops.