# Searching for flights that use (or not) Boeing or Airbus equipment

Tags: air-travel, bookings

Is there a way I can **search** (not just see after finding flights) for flights that use a particular maker's aircraft, say if I want to avoid or have a particular affinity to one of the major makers?

[This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/28975/how-can-i-know-about-the-type-of-the-airplane-before-booking) question is similar but ended up (3 years ago) with a suggestion on viewing the aircraft types after completing a search, which makes it quite tedious.

It should be possible to [make a list](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=290589) of airlines and use checkboxes on the search page to include only appropriate companies- but many companies (as just a couple of examples, Cathay Pacific and Hainan Airlines) run a mixed fleet directly or through their subsidiary connector airlines, complicating things, without even getting into codeshares.

Edit: Nate has pointed out a similar question with an answer that works for this situation.

Comment: @NateEldredge No that's to find  a particular type of aircraft, for example if you wanted to fly in an A380 for some reason.

Comment: But the accepted answer shows how to search for flights operated by one of an arbitrary list of types - so do a search with a list of all possible Airbus types (there are not that many) and you have what you want.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh, you're right- that IATA code list does the trick. Apologies.

Comment: Airlines swap equipment assigned to a route, so a B777 currently serving that route could be replaced by an A330 if demand drops.  Seems that would lead to upset travelers if they deliberately choose a Boeing flight and got an Airbus.

Comment: A code to avoid Boeing is "-aircraft t:703 t:707 t:70F t:70M t:717 t:721 t:722 t:727 t:72B t:72C t:72F t:72M t:72S t:72X t:72Y t:731 t:732 t:733 t:734 t:735 t:736 t:737 t:738 t:739 t:73C t:73F t:73G t:73H t:73J t:73M t:73W t:73X t:73Y t:741 t:742 t:743 t:744 t:747 t:74C t:74D t:74E t:74F t:74H t:74J t:74L t:74M t:74N t:74R t:74T t:74U t:74V t:74X t:74Y t:752 t:753 t:757 t:75F t:75M t:75T t:75W t:762 t:763 t:764 t:767 t:76F t:76W t:76X t:76Y t:772 t:773 t:777 t:77F t:77L t:77W t:788 t:789 t:B72"

Comment: Above code from [this](https://steemit.com/travel/@apertus-cogitari/how-progressive-travellers-can-boycott-boeing-and-why-general-electric-is-on-the-evil-list-as-well) website.